# Not able to select an element using protractor virtual repeat

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, end-to-end

I was able to select an element using `ng-repeat` but the developers have used virtual repeat as such the following code does not work now

```
expect(stores.listStores(0).getText()).toContain('Prahran');
expect(element.all(by.repeater('store in ui.stores')).count()).toEqual(1);
```

Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator by.repeater("store in ui.stores")

Comment: Can you show the HTML representation of the appropriate part of the page containing the repeater?

Comment: <div md-virtual-repeat="store in ui.stores" class="ng-scope">

Comment: Please put any relevant info (including the above HTML) into the question itself. It will make it easier to find and more likely that someone will answer your question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a CSS selector to match the material design repeater elements:

```
element.all(by.css('[md-virtual-repeat="store in ui.stores"]'));
```